# Python / CGI - Upload file attempt returns an empty page

Tags: python, upload, cgi

I really searched about 50 related pages but never seen a problem similar to my problem. When I press the submit button, it calls the script but the script returns an empty page and I see no file was uploaded. There is no typing error in my codes, I checked it several times and I really need this code running for my project. What might be the problem? I am running apache under ubuntu and my codes are:

html code:

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_file.py" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
</body></html>
```

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

try: #windows needs stdio set for binary mode
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY)
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
fileitem = form['file']

#if file is uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
    #strip leading path from filename to avoid directory based attacks
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    open('/files' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
    message = 'No file was uploaded'

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>
""" % (message,)
```

Comment: I don't know where to look for error logs in python cgi, can you help me for that?

Comment: Wherever your web server puts them.

Comment: I am using apache. Where is the default log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your script, with a few small corrections to the paths to make it work for me locally. With the paths set correctly, and permissions set properly, this code does work fine.

Here are the things to make sure of:

1. In your html file's form properties, make sure you are pointing to the python script that lives in a cgi-bin: `action="/cgi-bin/save_file.py"`. For me, I have a cgi-bin at the root of my web server, and I placed the python script there. It will not work if you are running the script from a standard document location on the web server
2. Make sure your save_file.py has executable permissions: `chmod 755 save_file.py`
3. In your save_file.py, ensure that you are building a valid path to open the file for saving. I made mine absolute just for testing purposes, but something like this: `open(os.path.join('/path/to/upload/files', fn)`

With those points set correctly, you should not have any problems.

Comment: Well here is my configuration:
Both my script files are under "/var/www/python/cgi-bin" and I applied chmod -R 755 to "/var/www/python" folder.
Finally files' folder path is "/var/www/python/cgi-bin/files" and I set the chmod 755 permission for save_file. What might be the issue? Do I have the right script for my paths?

Comment: @user1433743: Normally you wouldn't serve html out of the cgi-bin location. That would just be for cgi scripts and you would direct your urls to them from your standard document locations. But I don't think thats your problem. '/files', however is probably wrong. That is an absolute path on the local server to /files (not a url path), which is not "/var/www/python/cgi-bin/files". Try setting an absolute path.

Comment: I will.try to check the error log.because i did all you said and I still get the blank page and no uploads.

Comment: Can you send my mail (mehmetcan.oralalp@gmail.com) your apache http.conf file and mime.conf file because I applied all the steps you told me and still get the blank page.

Comment: @user1433743: I am using the default apache server built into OSX. I doubt it would be a 1-to-1 for you

Comment: Well at least is there a way for us to communicate tonight because I have an intense project due tomorrow and I need to set this up

Comment: I reinstalled apache with your configuration(exact folder design) and I checked the error log and it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/save_file.py", line 14, in <module>
    open(os.path.join('/var/www/cgi-bin/files', fn), 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/cgi-bin/files/cacert.der'
[Mon Jun 04 01:49:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: save_file.py, referer: http://localhost/form3.html

Comment: @user1433743: That means its actually trying to write your file but that cgi location has locked down permissions. Either `sudo chmod a+w /var/www/cgi-bin/files`, or set the files location to a more open place.

Comment: Mate I was about to lose it :) Finally I realized that the nautilus' properties gui does not function properly and set the permissions of 'files' to 777 and solved the problem. Thanks a lot by the way I will mention your name in my project tomorrow! :)

Comment: @user1433743: Thats great that it worked! Good luck on your project.